# How to validate email inside entity?

Tags: entity, clean-architecture

I got this user entity:

```
class User {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   email: string;
   password: string;

   ....
}
```

My business rules says that:
**One user per Email**

---

What's the purpose of this entity, It cannot have any dependencies. How can i check if email is unique or not?

The thing i don't understand is, who calls entity and pushes data inside it for validation and who can access it?(usecase or repository).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, when you need to satisfy this rule? Only when you are creating a new user. It does not make sense to check it when you've got a user from a database. Or when you are doing something with the user, like changing phonen umber, blocking and so on.

It means this behavior does not belong to `User` class. I would suggest to create some kind of `UserFactory` that creates a new user and inject there a policy (or policies).

```
    public UserFactory(EmailCheckingPolicy: emailpolicy, AnotherPolicy: somethingElse);

    public User create(UserData: userData) {
        if (emailPolicy.isPass(userData.email)) ...
        return User(userData.email, userData.name, ...)
    }
}
```

You can inject `UserFactory` to a UseCase.